# CSS div not respecting parent boundary

Tags: html, css, css-position

I'm trying to get a div within another div with a `max-height` set to respect that height, ultimately making the content within vertically scrollable.

I have a list series of labels within a div which have a `display:block` and they display correctly. The parent div expands to fit those labels breaking out of it's parents max-height, which is undesirable.

I've tried setting overflows as well as position relative on the parent and absolute on the child (containers) and vice versa without success. I would like to know why the `list-container` does not respect the `content-containers` `max-height` param.

```css
#container {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

#content-container {
    width: 500px;
    max-height: 20%;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 2%;
    font-size: 20px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

#list-container {
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    border: 1px solid green;
}

.list-item {
    /* width: 100%; */
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid salmon;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="content-container">
    <div id="list-container">
      <label class="list-item">Content 1</label>
      <label class="list-item">Content 2</label>
      <label class="list-item">Content 3</label>
      <label class="list-item">Content 4</label>
      <label class="list-item">Content 5</label>
      <label class="list-item">Content 6</label>
      <label class="list-item">Content 7</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it to be scrollable, you should use `overflow: auto` or `overflow: scroll`:

```css
#container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
#content-container {
  width: 500px;
  max-height: 20%;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 2%;
  font-size: 20px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
#list-container {
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
.list-item {
  /* width: 100%; */
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid salmon;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="content-container">
    <div id="list-container">
      <label class="list-item">Content 1</label>
      <label class="list-item">Content 2</label>
      <label class="list-item">Content 3</label>
      <label class="list-item">Content 4</label>
      <label class="list-item">Content 5</label>
      <label class="list-item">Content 6</label>
      <label class="list-item">Content 7</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Alternatively `overflow-y: scroll;` to avoid the horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: Additional question, how would I change this if I wanted the `list-container` to be the scrollable div?

I can get the scrollbars to show up on the `list-container`, but I can't seem to get it to stick within the sizing of the parent `content-container`

Comment: @JonFriesen `#content-container { height: 20% } #list-container { max-height: 100%; overflow: auto; box-sizing: border-box; }`

Comment: @Oriol -- thanks for your help! I appreciate the succinct answers :)

Answer (score 1):

Add `overflow: scroll;` to the `#content-container`

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0t70dyva/)

Answer (score 1):

```css
#container {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

#content-container {
    width: 500px;
    max-height: 20%;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 2%;
    font-size: 20px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    overflow:auto;    //or overflow:hidden?
}

#list-container {
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    border: 1px solid green;
}

.list-item {
    /* width: 100%; */
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid salmon;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="content-container">
    <div id="list-container">
      <label class="list-item">Content 1</label>
      <label class="list-item">Content 2</label>
      <label class="list-item">Content 3</label>
      <label class="list-item">Content 4</label>
      <label class="list-item">Content 5</label>
      <label class="list-item">Content 6</label>
      <label class="list-item">Content 7</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there. It is just missing `overflow: auto` on your `#content-container`. That way its area will be scrollable.

a code pen to help you understand:
http://codepen.io/sandrina-p/pen/akRQEY